# How to transmit only a subset of Wufoo entries to a web page?

Tags: wufoo

I have a Wufoo form that I use for lead generation. I now wish to create a public board of the leads, but with only a subset of the information (the objective is to get people interested to buy the leads by showing some information).

Therefore I need to be sure that the web page (which will be in public access) will only receive a subset of data.

I have tried using the solution described here:

http://www.wufoo.com/2011/01/24/partygoers/

which is a jQuery plugin that uses a PHP file to fetch data from Wufoo API. Though it seems to me that the complete data was received by the visitor's browser as JSON.

How can I transfer only a subset of the form entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this server side with PHP cURL as described in the [Wufoo API Documentation](http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/Wufoo-REST-API-V3)

I found it easier to ask for JSON and use PHP's `json_decode`

Then choose which data to output, to the page, from the resulting array.